# how to track file downloads in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I have a problem when trying to count downloads and send_file in the same action

here is my code

```
def download
    @file = FilmFile.find(params[:film_file_id])
    @file.film.downloads += 1
    @file.film.save
    send_file @file.real_name.path, content_type: @file.real_name.content_type
end
```

but when i watch a video from iphone system increase downloads by 3, and i see several get requests in logs. Is there a correct way to count downloads ? (i tried to create 2 actions: one for downloads count and another for sending file, but then 404 errors appearing when nginx tries to resume download)

because of large content size (video in my case) nginx has a lot of "206 partial content" in logs. I think the problem lies in resuming download by nginx

Comment: Do you mean that for each time you actually download and watch the video, the 'download' action seems to be getting called 2 or 3 times?  Do some of the requests fail, causing the app on the phone to try again?  If so then you'll need to find a way to distinguish between this in your rails app.  Without knowing anything about either of them it's hard to advise how to do this.

Comment: because of large content size (video in my case) nginx has a lot of "206 partial content" in logs. I think the problem lies in resuming download by nginx

Comment: It might be useful, while testing, to switch off 206s in nginx - see http://serverfault.com/questions/535889/disabling-206-partial-content-responses-on-nginx